# One high density folder instead of three folders

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the typical area of supporting multiple screen sizes for android. Basically, in my cards game it was really too much to provide the setof 52 cards duplicated for the 3 folders (ld, md, hd). The reasion is the increased app size by quite a bit.

So I was wondering, if I only provide high density folder then would the device scale down the images to appropriate densities. I mean if all what I was doing before was resizing the images down then the scaling down by the device would be same. right?

If  I do that (porviding only high density folder), will the image end up taking the same physical size on low density screen (I am using high density as it is generally to scal down than up).

Thank you

PS: Please don't give me the android website. I want your answer/experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, it *will* scale them down for you, but the resulting images will be lower in quality than those provided at the correct density, depending on how it is downscaled and by what percentage. It may or may not be that noticeable depending on the type of graphics, but fine lines and single-pixel details will be most noticeably different.

Comment: Wouldn't scaling though be the same as me using a program to resize the reoslution? So either way it will produce the same image exactly. Isn't that correct?

Comment: No, not really. There are all sorts of interpolation algorithms for rescaling content, and while by and large downscaling is not bad, there are certain subtle differences. For example, Photoshop has "Bilinear, Bicubic, Nearest Neighbor, Bicubic Sharper, Bicubic Smoother" interpolation modes. If you have very detailed artwork (icons, etc.) sometimes you may have to redraw existing portions for displaying at that smaller size. Overall? Try it and see. If you can't tell a noticeable difference then go for it. I'd recommend keeping it separate, personally.

Answer (score 0):

I have a game card too and i have put all my high-res cards in res.raw.
It should be the same in drawable-nodpi.

On all the device tested, the cards render very good. The phone just scale the cards up or down depending on the screen size.

Comment: if you put it in no-dpi it will disable scaling right? Plus do you mean "depedning on screen size" or "density size"